# Python library for apriori algorithm implementation on tabular data

Tags: library, python

I want a Python library which can implement the apriori algorithm, and is compatible with pandas data frames.

The data is binarized, which mean a 1 for an item, if it is included in a transaction, and 0 if it is not. So, a `T x n` dataframe.

```
T <-- number of transactions
n <-- number of possible items
```

Preferably open-source. (The Python version doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

[apyori](https://github.com/ymoch/apyori) implements this but not specifically for Pandas dataframes.
Adapting it to use them should be simple.